# CCSprite overlapping each other

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hi
 I am making a cocos2d game, In that i am adding enemies dynamically at different position, and animating them using action.

Enemies are appearing in screen according to the order I added. But I want to show sprites according to its Y value.

Please tell me is there any api in cocos2d to do sorting the sprites according to sprite position, or which is the best way to accomplish this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Best way to update zOrder based on Y position](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/3567)
- [Z Order Operations - "Perspective" based games](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15020)
- [CCSpriteBatchNode / reorder Z](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11273)